# How do I put a performclick in an if statement

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem.

I have 4 forms, 3 forms have the same button used for 1 form. I want to change the label in form 1 if one of these 3 forms button is pressed with performclick. But when I test it, it shows error "expression does not produce a value".

Is there any way to avoid that?

Here's my code:

```
 If FormPetugas.Button2.PerformClick Then
        Label1.Text = "Kode Petugas"
        Label2.Text = "Nama Petugas"
        Label3.Text = "Jenis Kelamin"
        Label4.Text = "Alamat Petugas"
        Label5.Text = "Nomor Telpon"
        Label6.Text = "Username"
        Label7.Text = "Password"
        Label8.Text = "Hak Akses"

        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Laki-laki")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Perempuan")

        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Administrasi")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("User Terpercaya")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("User Biasa")
    ElseIf FormKaryawan.Button2.PerformClick Then
        Label1.Text = "Kode Karyawan"
        Label2.Text = "Nama Karyawan"
        Label3.Text = "Jenis Kelamin"
        Label4.Text = "Alamat Karyawan"
        Label5.Text = "Nomor Telpon"
        Label6.Text = "Tanggal Pendaftaran"
        Label7.Text = "Ruangan"
        Label8.Text = "Status"

        ComboBox1.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Laki-laki")
        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Perempuan")

        ComboBox2.Items.Clear()
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Aktif")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Tidak Aktif")
        ComboBox2.Items.Add("Berhenti")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **avoid** it by removing `PerformClick()` from the If-statement. `PerformClick()` performs a fake click on the button, it is a method which **does not** return a value. You cannot check it in an If-statement.

You won't be able to check if a button was clicked with it because what `PerformClick()` does is just to invoke the paint event to make it look like the button is pressed, then it just calls `OnClick(EventArgs.Empty)` to raise all subscribed `Click` events.

**Refer to the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,845bec419ca23629).**

---

To check for regular clicks you would have to subscribe to the `Click` event:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Do stuff.
End Sub
```

Comment: So I have to move those stuffs to a certain button which triggers to call it?

Comment: @Rizky92 : I'm unsure what you mean, but yes I guess. The `Click` event will be raised when you click a button. There can be multiple subscribers to a single button's click event if one would like.

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked! I moved the labels to each of the button events and it works fine. I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: @Rizky92 : No problem! Please mark my post as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on it's left.